# How to make Angular tests wait for previous async operation to complete before executing

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap, angular-test, ngx-bootstrap-modal

In my Angular application test suite I have a test case doing the following:

```
it('test case with async operation', async(() => {
  // open modal

  // do some stuff

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    // do some async stuff and close the modal

    // some expetations
  });
}));
```

Everything works fine except that when this test actually finishes executing, the [modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) is still open (the `whenStable` callback will execute just a bit later, closing the modal). This makes other test failing since the modal will still be open for a little while.

Note that the modal is not part of the fixture component, so I queried it using `document.querySelector`

Note that the test case is wrapped into `async`.

The problem is that I have to wait for an async operationg inside the modal, which forces me to use `async` and `whenStable`. For this purpose, I've also tried to use `fakeAsync` and `tick` instead of `async`, but that would give me the error `error 1 timer(s) still in the queue`.

Comment: How did you use the `fakeAsync`-`tick` combination?

Comment: just like indicated in the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync)